# Default subtitle for videos

Tags: video-player

How can I set the default subtitle in wordpress videos?

Here is the shortcode that wp created after adding a video with a subtitle from media:

```
[video 
    width="960" 
    height="540" 
    mp4="example.com/wp-content/uploads/test.mp4"
]<track 
    srclang="En" 
    label="English" 
    kind="subtitles" 
    src="example.com/wp-content/uploads/test.vtt" 
/>[/video]
```

Now when I see the post in FO, I have to click on "cc" in video control bar and choose "English". The default is "None".

Now how can I change this default to English so that the user doesn't have to choose subtitle?

Answer (score 0):

From a UX perspective whether to display a subtitle track is a preference that should really be left up to the user.

Edit: that being said, mediaelement.js allows you to specify a starting sub track by passing in this option:

`{ startLanguage: 'en' }`

Comment: In general it may be true. But our business model is in a way that we play videos that our users don't understand the language of the video. All of them have to choose the local subtitle.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you. But I'm a newbie. Where should I put this line of code?

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery click on subtitle label

"en" srclang value.

```
if ($('#mep_0_track_0_subtitles_en').length > 0) 
    $('#mep_0_track_0_subtitles_en').trigger('click');
```